# mirt - odd results for nominal model

Tags: r

Using `mirt` package I obtained (possibly) odd results for my nominal model.

```
 library(difNLR)
 library(mirt)
 data("GMATtest", "GMATkey")
 key <- as.numeric(as.factor(GMATkey))
 data <- sapply(1:20, function(i) as.numeric(GMATtest[, i]))
 colnames(data) <- paste("Item", 1:ncol(data))
 scoredGMAT <- key2binary(data, key)

 # 2PL IRT model for scored data
 mod0 <- mirt(scoredGMAT, 1)
 # nominal model for unscored data
 mod1 <- mirt(data, 1, 'nominal')

# plots of characteristic curves for item 1
itemplot(mod0, 1)
itemplot(mod1, 1)
```

[image][image]

I expected that for the nominal model `mod1` there will be one curve very similar to the correct answer as plotted for my `mod0`. However, it seems that distractors have increasing probability with increasing theta, which seems not really reasonable. Of course, there can be something wrong with data or (more probably) I'm missing something..

I have already checked examples in `mirt` help and results are as I expected.

Any suggestions (what may be wrong) would be appreciated!

One last thing - I also tried to fit `2PLNRM` model but my R session aborted. Anybody noticed same issue? My code:

```
# 2PLNRM model
mod2 <- mirt(data, 1, "2PLNRM", key = key)
coef(mod2)$`Item 1`
itemplot(mod2, 1)
```

**EDIT:**
There is an example from `mirt` package:

```
library(mirt)
data(SAT12)
SAT12[SAT12 == 8] <- NA #set 8 as a missing value
head(SAT12)

# correct answer key
key <- c(1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
         3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5)
scoredSAT12 <- key2binary(SAT12, key)
mod0 <- mirt(scoredSAT12, 1)

# for first 5 items use 2PLNRM and nominal
scoredSAT12[, 1:5] <- as.matrix(SAT12[, 1:5])
mod1 <- mirt(scoredSAT12, 1, c(rep('nominal', 5), rep('2PL', 27)))

coef(mod0)$Item.1
coef(mod1)$Item.1

itemplot(mod0, 1)
itemplot(mod1, 1)
```

And the results are what I expected, however, when I try to fit `nominal` model for all items, curves changed:

```
# nominal for all items
mod1 <- mirt(SAT12, 1, 'nominal')
coef(mod1)$Item.1
itemplot(mod1, 1)
```

So, as you suggested, it seems that theta and its interpretation changed, but why and how?

Comment: Note that if P1 is the correct answer, then it has increasing probability with decreasing theta, the opposite of the distractors. In this sense, the modelling would makes sense. Have you checked the other items to verify if this behavior is consistent?

Comment: Note sure I uderstand, but checking P1 it seems to be descreasing and not increasing. As it is the correct answer, the modelling doesn't make sense to me. Other items seem to be similar.

Comment: If for all items, the correct answer is always the one with theta decreasing, and the distractors are the ones with theta increasing, then the results given by `mirt` are consistent.
But then we have to rethink what theta means in this type of modelling for this specific case, and that's not a code related question.

Comment: I updated my question. I rerun example from `mirt` package. When fitting `nominal` model for only first 5 items, everything seems to be in line with `2PL` model. But when I tried to fit `nominal` for all items, slopes of curves changed. So as you suggested, this may mean that interpretation of theta changed. It seems to me that it is now minus original theta (or very similar) interpreting as "ignorance" (?)

Comment: Well I also examined factor scores and it is the case as I expected. When fitting all `nominal` vs all `2PL` the relationship between factor scores is linear with intercept equals almost to 0 and with intercept of -1 (almost). When fitting only one item as `nominal` there is some bias in theta but it is almost the same as the original theta.. Well, thanks for your ideas, now I know what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Juan Bosco is correct that this behaviour is consistent. The issue with using the nominal response model for all items is that the direction of an increasing $\theta$ value is not obvious in the model because it's direction is arbitrary (the items are 'unordered' by default, after all).

Moreover, because of `mirt`'s default parameterisation, which assumes that the lowest/highest numerical category should be associated with low/high $\theta$ values, this type of flipping is common in multiple choice-type items (where, unlike rating scale ordered data, there should be no direct relationship) because the model will pick the orientation that best matches with these identification constraints.

To fix this, simply redefine the scoring constraints used by `mirt` by replacing the highest fixed scoring coefficient to the actual scoring key provided. Like so:

```
#starting values data.frame
sv <- mirt(data, 1, 'nominal', pars = 'values')
head(sv)

# set all values to 0 and estimated
sv$value[grepl('ak', sv$name)] <- 0
sv$est[grepl('ak', sv$name)] <- TRUE

nms <- colnames(data)
for(i in 1:length(nms)){

    #set highest category based on key fixed to 3
    pick <- paste0('ak', key[i]-1)
    index <- sv$item == nms[i] & pick == sv$name
    sv[index, 'value'] <- 3
    sv[index, 'est'] <- FALSE

    # set arbitrary lowest category fixed at 0
    if(pick == 'ak0') pick2 <- 'ak3'
    else pick2 <- paste0('ak', key[i]-2)
    index2 <- sv$item == nms[i] & pick2 == sv$name
    sv[index2, 'est'] <- FALSE
}

#estimate
mod2 <- mirt(data, 1, 'nominal', pars=sv)
plot(mod2, type = 'trace')
itemplot(mod2, 1)
coef(mod2, simplify=TRUE)
```

At the very least, this informs the model which category is the highest, and therefore provides enough information to finish with a more appropriate orientation. Note that it really doesn't affect the interpretation of the model per say, because all that happens is the slopes are multiplied by -1 and the scoring coefs are adjusted accordingly. HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive comment! It is very useful. That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Well, as suggested by Juan, the problem is that estimate of theta is changed when using different IRT model. Moreover there is some connection between the estimates by `2PL` and `nominal` model.

```
library(difNLR)
library(mirt)
data("GMATtest", "GMATkey")
key <- as.numeric(as.factor(GMATkey))
data <- sapply(1:20, function(i) as.numeric(GMATtest[, i]))
colnames(data) <- paste("Item", 1:ncol(data))
scoredGMAT <- key2binary(data, key)

# 2PL IRT model for scored data
mod0 <- mirt(scoredGMAT, 1)
# nominal model for unscored data
mod1_all <- mirt(data, 1, 'nominal')
# nominal model for only first item
df <- data.frame(data[, 1], scoredGMAT[, 2:20])
mod1_1 <- mirt(df, 1, c('nominal', rep('2PL', 19)))

# plots of characteristic curves for item 1
itemplot(mod0, 1)
itemplot(mod1_all, 1)
itemplot(mod1_1, 1)

# factor scores
fs0 <- fscores(mod0)
fs1_all <- fscores(mod1_all)
fs1_1 <- fscores(mod1_1)


plot(fs1_all ~ fs0)
plot(fs1_1 ~ fs0)
```

[image]

```
# linear model
round(coef(lm(fs1_all ~ fs0)), 4)

(Intercept)         fs0 
    -0.0001     -0.9972
```

This seems that new theta is sth like 'ignoration' rather than 'knowledge', as it's almost minus original theta.

Thank you Juan for your ideas, they were really helpful!